# Cannot log onto new accounts - "The User Profile Service failed the logon. User profile cannot be loaded"

Tags: windows, user-accounts, user-profiles

I'm on a fairly new install of Win 7 x64 with default UAC settings. I recently had to delete a user profile due to the win 7 2012 virus issue, but when trying to create a new profile (any profile name), while it creates it in the UI, when I try to log onto it, I get the error above.

I see lots of tips about fixing a corrupt profile in the registry (the S-1-5-XXX keys), but this is for a NEW profile.

The only way I seem to be able to get around this is to create the user account in safe mode. After that, I'm able to log in. After multiple reboots, I cannot seem to do this without being in safe mode. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm betting the virus screwed with some system files. From Safe Mode, open a Command Prompt as Administrator, and type 'sfc /scannow'. Let the scan run, then reboot. If this doesn't fix it, you may need to backup your data files and reinstall

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve it. It came down to messed up permissions on c:\users\default and couldn't create the new user folder. Thanks.

Comment: What were the permissions required for successful user creation process?

Comment: [KB 148437](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/148437) lists the permissions but that's not causing the problem for me.